# How to use condition queues properly

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a taskList object "holder" that contains a list of "task" objects. In a loop i read commands from a text file and on each line i add new task object with a command and add it into the "holder" object. The commands are of the form "cat source_file1 source_file2 output_file", if one of the files are missing i want the thread to wait, and proceed further with the new commands. I am trying to use a condition queue with the following predicate (if both files for the command exists wake up and do the work) until then sleep. I am using two threads for testing purpose when the first thread enters the wait state the program hangs forever and it not gives a chance to the other threads to produce the file that is missed for the waited thread.

```
public class MyTaskManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        TaskHolder holder = new TaskHolder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    BufferedReader br = null;
                    try {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                new FileInputStream("commands.txt")));
                        String line = "";
                        while  ( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null) {
                            String[] in = line.split(" ");
                            File dep0 = new File(in[1]), dep1 = new File(in[2]);

                            holder.addTask(new Task(dep0, dep1));

                            synchronized (holder) {
                                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                                while (!dep0.exists() || !dep1.exists()) {
                                    holder.wait();
                                }


                            }
                            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime()
                                    .exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", in[0] + " " + in[1] + " " + in[2]});
                            process.getInputStream().transferTo(new FileOutputStream(in[3]));

                            holder.notifyAll();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            threads.add(t);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            threads.get(i).start();


        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            try {
                threads.get(i).join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

```
public class TaskHolder {
    private List<Task> taskList;

    TaskHolder() {
        taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void addTask(Task task) {
        taskList.add(task);
    }

    List<Task> getTaskList() {
        return taskList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no call to `notify`. Also, the `holder` you are synchronizing on doesn't actually protect anything. You have to use the lock to protect the shared state that you are waiting for a change in.

It sounds like you don't understand the point of conditions nor how they work. Simply put, they provide an atomic "unlock and wait" operation to fix the following problem:

1. To check some shared state, we must hold a lock.
2. To wait for the shared state to change, we must release the lock so another thread can change the shared state.

This will allow a deadlock without an atomic "unlock and wait" operation. That's what `wait` is for -- it's an atomic "unlock and wait" to avoid the race condition if you unlock and then wait. If that's not the problem you have, then `wait` is not the solution you need!

And that's not the problem that you have. So these aren't the droids you are looking for. Don't use `synchronized` -- it's for communication between threads. And don't use `wait`, it's for when you need an atomic "unlock and wait" operation to avoid a race condition.

Comment: I edited the code like you say to have the predicate change i must  release the lock and you say  "You have to use the lock to protect the shared state that you are waiting for a change in." -> in this case i need dep0 and dep1 to be composite in the holder object itself or ? My idea is if some thread don't have the file right now it can be added later by another threads and just to continue from there. Isn't this suitable for the case ? Thank you for the help.

Comment: @BorisBorovski Yes, but the thread that modifies the shared state must hold the lock when it does it and it must call some `notify` function.